# Get counts of exact matches for tuple in a nested list of tuples

Tags: python, list, count, comparison, tuples

I have a list that contains multiple lists of tuples. I want to compare each tuple to every other tuple in the lists and return a count of the exact matches.

```
    foo = [[('a',),('a','b'),('a','b','c'),('b','c'),('c',)],[('a',),('a','b')]]
```

Expected results:

```
('a',)        2
('a','b')     2
('a','b','c') 1 
('b','c')     1
('c',)        1
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import collections
>>>
>>> foo = [[('a',),('a','b'),('a','b','c'),('b','c'),('c',)],[('a',),('a','b')]]
>>> for x, cnt in collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(foo)).most_common():
...     print(x, cnt)
...
('a',) 2
('a', 'b') 2
('a', 'b', 'c') 1
('c',) 1
('b', 'c') 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge all the lists into one, and then you can use [`Collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), like this

```
foo = [[('a',),('a','b'),('a','b','c'),('b','c'),('c',)],[('a',),('a','b')]]
from collections import Counter
print Counter(item for items in foo for item in items)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({('a', 'b'): 2, ('a',): 2, ('b', 'c'): 1, ('c',): 1, ('a', 'b', 'c'): 1})
```

The same result can be achieved with normal `dict` as well

```
result = {}
for items in foo:
    for item in items:
        result[item] = result.get(item, 0) + 1
print result
```

**Output**

```
{('b', 'c'): 1, ('c',): 1, ('a', 'b'): 2, ('a',): 2, ('a', 'b', 'c'): 1}
```